# PHP DatePeriod error when using DateInterval to loop over months

Tags: php

I am using a DateInterval object to loop over months. However when running the following code below:

```
 $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
 $daterange = new DatePeriod('2017-08-01', $interval , '2017-10-01');

 foreach($daterange as $d){
  $start_date = $d->format("Y-m-d");

 echo $start_date;
}

//Expected Output:
// 2017-08-01
// 2017-09-01
```

Gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DatePeriod::__construct(): This constructor accepts either (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, int) OR (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, DateTime) OR (string) as arguments.' in C:.. Stack trace: #0 C:\..: DatePeriod->__construct('2017-08-01', Object(DateInterval), '2017-10-01') #1 {main} thrown in C:\..
```

How can I get the expected output?

Comment: The first argument to `new DatePeriod()` has to be a `DateTimeInterface`, not a string. The third argument has to be `int` or `DateTime`, not a string.

Comment: did you bother to look at the first example in the documentation? It shows how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DateTime instead of string.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2017-08-01');
$end = new DateTime('2017-10-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
```

As @Barmar mentioned you can also use integer instead of `$end` as the third argument.

```
$begin = new DateTime('2017-08-01');
$recurrences = 1;
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $recurrences);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DatePeriod` constructor is not used correctly. See the official reference [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php).

Try this:

```
$daterange = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2017-08-01'), 
    $interval , 
    new DateTime('2017-10-01')
);
```